# How can I get the Full Cygwin Installation (about 1GB)?

Tags: cygwin

I want to install Cygwin Full (about 1GB) but I cannot find any site offering it anymore. There [was one](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=3Y0KDJLZ) but the [Internet Archive did not back it up](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.megaupload.com/?d=3Y0KDJLZ), after someone killed the site.

Some [instructions about installation are here](http://www.technixupdate.com/download-cygwin-full-setup-offline-installer/).

How can I get it and is there some trusted source with hashes to verify the dump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thousands of packages.. Creating a static dump of them will be outdated in day. I know what you mean.. But the best bet is to do the effort once, keep them updated and backup before deleting again.

[Cygwin installation guide](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages) says,

> By default, setup.exe will install only the packages in the Base
>   category and their dependencies, resulting in a minimal Cygwin
>   installation. However, this will not include many commonly used tools
>   such as gcc (which you will find in the Devel category). Since
>   setup.exe automatically selects dependencies, be careful not to
>   unselect any required packages. In particular, everything in the Base
>   category is required.

So, if you know which packages you need, its not much of a trouble, because the most important ones will be installed by default. You can always install any package you want after you've installed Cygwin. There is no need to install them all at once go.

Comment: i'm sure most people(apart from the OP perhaps) are aware that you can do it very manually what you call 'doing the effort' and while you say about backing it up you don't   state how.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the easy way of getting the full Cygwin.

Run the Cygwin setup.exe file (You can download it at [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html)). Choose your options and click next until you reach a screen that shows the list of packages.

If your 'select packages' screen looks different from mine, just click the 'View' button near the top-right again and again until the text next to view is 'Category', just like mine.

[image: old Cygwin screenshot]

Update: In the new Cygwin interface, click the drop-down next to the View label in the top left and select Category. Thanks to simlev for the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1219884/246049).

[image]

Next, click the 'Default' next to 'All'.

[image]

Now all packages are selected!

[image]

(The last step is to just do the rest of the steps the setup program tells you to do.).

If you need to 'update' your current Cygwin to have all the new packages without deleting your old ones etc., then this info from [Cygwin.com](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages) should be useful:

> Once you have an existing Cygwin installation, the setup.exe chooser
>   is also used to manage your Cygwin installation. Information on
>   installed packages is kept in the /etc/setup/ directory of your Cygwin
>   installation; if setup.exe cannot find this directory it will act as
>   if you have no Cygwin installation. If setup.exe finds a newer version
>   of an installed package available, it will automatically mark it to be
>   upgraded. To Uninstall, Reinstall, or get the Source for an existing
>   package, click on Keep to toggle it. Also, to avoid the need to reboot
>   after upgrading, make sure to close all Cygwin windows and stop all
>   Cygwin processes before setup.exe begins to install the upgraded
>   package.
>
> To avoid unintentionally upgrading, use the Pending view to see which
>   packages have been marked for upgrading. If you don't want to upgrade
>   a package, click on the new version number to toggle it until it says
>   Keep. All packages can be set to stay at the installed version by
>   pressing the Keep button in the top right part of the chooser window.
>
> A previous version of each package is usually available, in case
>   downgrading is required to avoid a serious bug in the current version
>   of the package. Packages also occasionally have testing (or
>   "experimental") versions available. Previous and experimental versions
>   can be chosen by clicking on the package's New column until the
>   required version appears.
>
> All available experimental packages can be selected by pressing the
>   Exp in the top right part of the chooser window. Be warned, however,
>   that the next time you run setup.exe it will try to replace all old or
>   experimental versions with the current version, unless told otherwise.

By the way, I installed full Cygwin (except the games and without obsolete, but with some minor [at least I think so] additional required dependencies). The total size is about 5.51 GB for the compressed, downloaded packages, whereas the cygwin software which has all the uncompressed packages is 16.1 GB (Size on disk is 17.1 GB). Both of these are stored in separate directories, so assuming you keep the compressed, downloaded packages this takes a total disk space of about 22 GB. Downloading and installing took me about 10 hours, which should vary of course.

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1, deleted my answer in deference to this one.

Comment: This is a top-notch answer, but Cygwin has changed the installer's user interface enough enough that this answer would help.

Comment: Would you be willing to post an updated answer, either on this question or my new https://superuser.com/questions/1219722/how-can-i-do-a-cygwin-full-install-with-the-new-installer ? Thanks,

Comment: @JonathanHayward Thank you for the request, I have updated the answer with screenshot from the new interface.

Answer (score 4):

If you have **rsync** then here is a simple one-line approach.

```
rsync --partial -va rsync://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/release/ /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/release/
```

Just replace source with your local mirror or whatever is the fastest.
I normally have a script, under `/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/sync-with-cygwin-mirror.sh` so it would update to the latest and greatest :-)

### Example script

```
cat > /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/sync-with-cygwin-mirror.sh <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
#
###
# Choose mirror that is on http://www.cygwin.com/mirrors.html
#
# "ftp://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/"
# "ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/lang/cygwin/"
# "http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/"
#
# Old
# "http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/mirrors.lst"
###
rsync --partial -va rsync://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/release/ /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/release/
#
EOF
chmod +x /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/sync-with-cygwin-mirror.sh
```

Comment: [Here are a list of cygwin repositories.](http://www.cygwin.com/mirrors.html)

Comment: Assuming  California, for instance, use the web browser and [look at the HTML download page](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/) from the above link.  From there, it can be seen that the path on that server to the x86_64 release of cygwin can be found in `sourceware/cygwin`, for which the rsync command could be derived as:  `$ rsync --partial -va rsync://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86_64 .`

Comment: This is the easiest way. Its working and downloaded all packages of cygwin. Its comes around 23GB

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the `pmcyg` tool ([SourceForge page](http://pmcyg.sourceforge.net)), which should run on any machine that has Python-2.x installed on it.

Something of the form:

```
pmcyg --nogui --all
```

Will automatically mirror the entire set of `Cygwin` packages and installer for the x86 architecture. Adding the `--remove-outdated yes` option will allow you to repeatedly update your local mirror as new Cygwin packages are released.

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't want to spend hours downloading it, you can use a simple tool I've created that finds the fastest mirror:
[Cygwin Mirror Tester](https://gist.github.com/devnoname120/10009977)