# How can I do a Cygwin full install with the new installer?

Tags: windows, installation, unix, cygwin, emulation

In [How can I get the Full Cygwin Installation (about 1GB)?](https://superuser.com/questions/383507/how-can-i-get-the-full-cygwin-installation-about-1gb), Bibhas's answer gives detail and helpful screenshot for what the Cygwin installer's UI was for years.

That installer behavior has changed; the UI works differently, and I may have figured out how to request a full install be downloaded, but I'm not positive.

What is the preferred way to do a Cygwin full install given the installer's new UI?

Thanks,

**--UPDATE--**

Per comment, this is a screenshot of what I was getting initially, which was unfamiliar to me.[image]

Comment: Could you point out the differences and explain where you get stuck? Some illustrative screenshots would help.

Comment: @simlev Thank you; could you review the screenshot? I was slightly baffled compared to what setup had given me before.

Comment: I take you refer to raindrop's answer and not Bibhas', since it's the only one that includes any screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean, now that you've added the screenshot. Let me highlight this sentence from the referenced answer:

> If your 'select packages' screen looks different from mine, just click the 'View' button near the top-right again and again until the text next to view is 'Category', just like mine.

In your version of the installer, there's no View button, so I guess that's where you get stuck. You simply have to select Category from the drop-down next to the View label in the top left.